# Haskell - how to create a function that returns the fifth element from a list

Tags: list, function, haskell

How to create a function in Haskell that returns the fifth element from a list.

Something like this:

```
fifth [] = []!!4
```

Should return this:

```
*Main> fifth [1,2,3,20,30,40]
30
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply use:

```
fifth :: [a] -> a
fifth l = l !! 4
```

Using `fifth []` like you suggest is wrong since that will pattern match the list against the empty list — you simply want to bind a variable name to the full list so that you can use the `!!` function afterwards.

You can even define the function as:

```
fifth :: [a] -> a
fifth = (!!4)
```

Here we use [*partial application*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application): you normally think of `!!` as a function taking two arguments: a list and an integer. We can provide it with one of the arguments and get a new function (`fifth`) that only takes a list. When we provide `(!!4)` with a list, it returns the fifth element:

```
Prelude> let fifth = (!!4)
Prelude> fifth [1,2,3,20,30,40]
30
```

The function is of course a *partial* function since it will fail for small lists:

```
Prelude> (!!4) [1,2,3,20]
*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large
```

That's to be expected. If you want, you can make it safe by letting it return `Maybe a` instead of `a`::

```
fifth :: [a] -> Maybe a
fifth (a:b:c:d:e:rest) = Just e
fifth _ = Nothing
```

Here the first pattern will match lists of length 5 or more, and the second pattern matches anything not matched by the first. You use it like this:

```
*Main> fifth [1,2,3,20,30,40]
Just 30
*Main> fifth [1,2,3,20]
Nothing
```

You have now **forced** yourself to always pattern match the result of `fifth` against either `Just a` or `Nothing`. This means that when you code calls `fifth someList`, then it **must** take into account that `someList` might be too short. That way you can ensure at *compile time* that there wont be any *runtime* errors from this function.

Comment: +1 @Martn `You have now forced yourself ...` unless he discovers how to write unJust, that is .....

Comment: @Ingo: shhh, let's keep that between you and me :-)

Answer (score 8):

I would define a safe-indexing operator `!!!` and then define `fifth` in terms of `!!!`.

```
(!!!)                  :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
xs       !!! n | n < 0 =  Nothing
[]       !!! _         =  Nothing
(x : _)  !!! 0         =  Just x
(_ : xs) !!! n         =  xs !!! (n - 1)

fifth :: [a] -> Maybe a
fifth =  (!!! 4)
```

Comment: That's a nice generalization of my answer, I like!

Answer (score 5):

Another **unsafe** variant would be

```
fifth = head . drop 4
```

But hey, sometimes one just knows this damn list will have more than 4 elements. The type system is just not powerful enough to express it (using standard lists, that is).

Comment: Safe version: `fifth = listToMaybe . drop 4`